# Able to access private data members with gcc, while clang complains appropriately

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

How come the following code compiles with `gcc-4.8` with no problem, while using `clang-3.6` generates appropriate error:

> "error: 'value_type' is a private member of 'B'"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct B {
private:
    typedef int value_type;
};

int main () {
    std::cout << std::is_same< B::value_type, int >::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Detail : `value_type` isn't a private *data* member of `B`.

Comment: It's a bug in your old version of gcc. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8NMiAJuJgum9j8et

Comment: gcc-4.8 is a pretty old compiler. Its a bug. reproduced [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wpyNW9yF4zMf5Fna). This bug was fixed since gcc-4.9. As seen [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KMlCyYpFI1WQFMqd)

Comment: @François Andrieux And what is the typedef?  What does it have control access?